# fit of translate curve and restore translation

Tags: functions

I have a set of data, $S$ with negative values and the function.

$$
\begin{equation}
y = x + s \sqrt{ m \frac{x}{s} + 1}
\end{equation}
$$

If I try fit the curve for get the parameters $m$ and $s$, I have some problems with the negative values and the square root.

For this I make a translation of the function

$$
\begin{equation}
y = (x+t) + s \sqrt{ m \frac{ (x+t)}{s} + 1} 
\end{equation}
$$

with this translation I can make the fit (with curve_fit of scipy python library) and I get the parameters $s$ and $m$.

but, with the paramenters in translation, how I can get the paramenters in the original equation ?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be stupid to start with a fit of

(y-x)^2 = s * m * x + s = a * x + s

A linear regression will give you "a" and "s" and them "m = a / s". These could be good estimates to start with using a non linear fit.